# curry functions using generic type

Tags: scala

I am trying to use curry a function with typed class. my goal is the classes that extends that class will only have to define the curried function . this is my last failed attempt :

```
  abstract class Foo[T: Ordering]{
    def eval(x: T, y: T)(f:(T,T)=>Option[Boolean])(implicit ev:Ordering[T] = null): Option[Boolean] = {
      if(ev == null)
          None
        else
          f(x,y)
    }
  }
  case object Bar extends Foo{
    def xx[T: Ordering] = (x:T,y:T)=>Some(x>y)
    eval(xx)
  }
```

how should it be done correctly ?

Comment: I don't think you can encode optional implicits very well like this.

Comment: @Daenyth well, it works ... Couldn't find a better way to return none in case one sends an unknown object to the method

Comment: @igx You shouldn't add a default value to implicit parameters: It's really dangerous. The compiler should complain if no implicit parameter is in scope and clients that don't want to provide a value for `ev` should do this explicitely. Also: I don't fully understand what you want to achieve. Why don't you make `f` an unimplemented protected member of `Foo`?

Comment: @KuluLimpa the reason that I'm giving a default value is because I want to return None in case someone sends invalid value to the eval method . so if someone sends something like this eval(Bar,2) the method returns None (where Bar can be anything like case object Bar ) . is there any other way to achieve that ?

Comment: @igx However, `eval(Bar, 2)` is only statically prohibited if you choose `T` as `Any`, which you can only do if there is an implicit ordering on `Any` in scope (because of the generic parameter on `Foo`) What this implies is that the whole `implicit ev: Ordering[T] = null` parameter isn't necessary, which in return implies that `eval(x: T, y: T)(f: (T, T) => Option[Boolean]) = f(x, y)`, making `eval` a mere alias for `f`. Can you give the context in which you want to apply `eval`, because even attempting to get a result for `eval(Bar, 2)` doesn't make sense to me - it just shouldn't compile.

Comment: @KuluLimpa actually you are correct it does "smell". I am creating and object with reflection and I thought how to avoid throwing and exception in case  it cannot be compared

Comment: @igx Now that you mention reflection this question makes a lot more sense. Maybe you should update the question. However, this may just be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). One problem with your attempt is that implicit conversion happens statically, while reflection is a run-time thing. Have you considered using `Try{/*Code using reflection and calling eval*/}`, which returns either `Success(resultOfEval)` or `Failure(exception)`. IMO this is cleaner than returning an option and may solve your problem.